# apache access_log filename use server hostname

Tags: apache, hostname, access-log

How apache `access_log` filename use server hostname

```
ex)
[root@testserver ~]# hostname
testserver

vi httpd-vhosts.conf

CustomLog "|/usr/local/cronolog/sbin/cronolog --symlink=/home/apache_log/www/access_log /home/apache_log/www/$HOSTNAME_access_log.%Y%m%d"

testserver_access_log.20130809
```